# Google Apps Script - Impossible operation with an element inside a shared drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I need your help on something.

I did a function which goal is to make a copy of a template file and put it in a folder in a shared drive. The problem is that the program returns :

> "Exception: This operation cannot be performed on an item in a shared Drive"

Yet, I have all the permissions in that shared drive so I don't understand.

I did several tweaks and I've founded that `removeFile` and `addFile` are parts of the problem. If I don't run them, the folder is created and the copy is made. But I still need the file to be  moved.

I hope someone can help me with this.

PS : You can fin my code below.

```js
function makeCopyFile(folderID, fileID, newName) {
  var getFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
  var copyFile = file.makeCopy();
  var newFile = copyFile.setName(newName);
  
  // Remove the file from all parent folders
  var parents = newFile.getParents();
  while (parents.hasNext()) {
    var parent = parents.next();
    parent.removeFile(newFile);
  }
  getFolder.addFile(newFile);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem is that you are trying to delete a file on a shared drive with `DriveApp`

It will work if you do it instead with the [Advanced Drive service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) where you can specify `"supportsAllDrives": true`

So, after enabling the Advanced Service: replace

```
  var parents = newFile.getParents();
  while (parents.hasNext()) {
    var parent = parents.next();
    parent.removeFile(newFile);
  }
```

through

```
  var id = copyFile.getId();
  // or alternatively  `var id = newFile.getId();` - because it is the same
  Drive.Files.remove(id,{"supportsAllDrives": true})
```

**As for `getFolder.addFile(newFile);`**

Once you remove a file, you cannot add it back anymore. Also, I do not understand your motivation for it - `copyFile.setName(newName);` is enough to rename the file - you do not need to delete the file with the old name and insert the one with the new name.

### UPDATE

If your goal is to copy a file to a team drive folder, you can do it easily as following with the Drive API:

```
function  makeCopyFile(folderID, fileID, newName){
  var resource = {
  "parents": [
    {
      "id": folderID
    }
  ],
  "title": newName
}
  Drive.Files.copy(resource, fileID, {"supportsAllDrives": true})
}
```

Comment: *Also, I do not understand your motivation for it* OP wants to move the copiedFile `newFile` from `Folder1` to `Folder2`(both folders being in the same shared drive). He's not trying to delete any file.

Comment: `parent.removeFile(newFile);`

Comment: It only removes the file from it's parent. It doesn't even trash it. From the documentation, [*This method does not* **delete** *the file, but if a file is removed from all of its parents, it cannot be seen in Drive except by searching for it or using the "All items" view.*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#removefilechild)